# mousewheel smooth scroll with elemen animation

Tags: jquery, scroll, mousewheel, gsap

I have a some code:

```js
var rellax = new Rellax('.rellax',{
  center: false,
  wrapper: null,
  round: true,
  vertical: true,
  horizontal: false
});


// TweenMax
$(function(){
 
 var $window = $(window);  //Window object
 
 var scrollTime = 1.2;   //Scroll time
 var scrollDistance = 170;  //Distance. Use smaller value for shorter scroll and greater value for longer scroll
  
 $window.on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function(event){
  
  event.preventDefault(); 
          
  var delta = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta/120 || -event.originalEvent.detail/3;
  var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
  var finalScroll = scrollTop - parseInt(delta*scrollDistance);
    
    //console.log(finalScroll);
      
      $('.leaf>img').css({ 'transform' : 'rotateX(0deg)' });
      //$('.leaf>img').removeClass('rotate');
   
  TweenMax.to($window, scrollTime, {
          scrollTo : { y: finalScroll, autoKill:true },
          ease: Power1.easeOut, 
          autoKill: true,
          overwrite: 5,
          onComplete: function() {
            $('.leaf>img').css({ 'transform' : 'rotateX(50deg)' });
            //$('.leaf').addClass('rotate');
          }
        });
     
 });
 
});

// MouseWheel
// if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
// window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;

// function wheel(event) {
//     var delta = 0;
//     if (event.wheelDelta) delta = event.wheelDelta / 220;
//     else if (event.detail) delta = -event.detail / 3;

//     handle(delta);
//     if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
//     event.returnValue = false;
// }

// var goUp = true;
// var end = null;
// var interval = null;

// function handle(delta) {
//  var animationInterval = 20; //lower is faster
//     var scrollSpeed = 20; //lower is faster

//  if (end == null) {
//    end = $(window).scrollTop();
//   }
//   end -= 20 * delta;
//   goUp = delta > 0;

//   if (interval == null) {
//     interval = setInterval(function () {
//       var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
//       var step = Math.round((end - scrollTop) / scrollSpeed);
//       if (scrollTop <= 0 || 
//           scrollTop >= $(window).prop("scrollHeight") - $(window).height() ||
//           goUp && step > -1 || 
//           !goUp && step < 1 ) {
//         clearInterval(interval);
//         interval = null;
//         end = null;
//       }
//       $(window).scrollTop(scrollTop + step );
//     }, animationInterval);
//   }
// }
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size:20px;
  line-height: 2rem;
  
  position: relative;
}


img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transform-origin:50% 50%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

main {
  padding: 2rem 3rem;
  text-align: center; 
}

.leaf {
  display: block;
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 0;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 20vw;
  
  -webkit-perspective: 500px;
  perspective: 500px;
  
}

/* .rotate {
  animation: rotate 1s ease-in-out;
}


@keyframes rotate {
  from { transform: rotateX(0deg); }
  50% {transform: rotateX(50deg);}
  to { transform: rotateX(0deg); }
} */

.l-2 {
  margin-left: 30%;
}
.l-3 {
  margin-left: 70%;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: -10%;
  
  -webkit-perspective: 500px;
  perspective: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rellax/1.7.1/rellax.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/plugins/ScrollToPlugin.min.js"></script>

<header id="scene">

  <span data-rellax-speed="-2" data-rellax-percentage="0.5" class="rellax leaf l-1">
    <img src="https://pics.clipartpng.com/midle/Leaf_PNG_Clip_Art-1968.png" alt="" >
  </span>

  <span data-rellax-speed="-3" data-rellax-percentage="0.5" class="rellax leaf l-2">
    <img src="https://png2.kisspng.com/20180201/pye/kisspng-maple-leaf-clip-art-maple-leaf-5a72a608f0a8c5.3016083115174630489858.png" alt="" >
  </span>

  <span data-rellax-speed="-1" data-rellax-percentage="0.75" class="rellax leaf l-3">
    <img src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/green-leaf-png-9.png" alt="" >
  </span>

</header>
<main>
  <h1>Smooth Scroll</h1>
  <h2>Use your mousewheel to scroll</h2>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur natus, facere nulla similique doloremque! Ullam voluptatem debitis esse. Deleniti quas, vel ad consectetur facilis ab consequatur voluptate aut optio odit nisi reprehenderit sint, ipsa incidunt itaque id voluptatum repudiandae alias esse velit quo voluptatibus recusandae earum eligendi! Est, quae, aliquam?
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, earum ullam hic id! Corporis cupiditate, voluptatibus eligendi suscipit ratione eos, sequi aperiam voluptatem laboriosam! Debitis consectetur eum aperiam similique ullam dolore, labore porro, sequi fuga atque, tempora, est delectus veniam! Ad tempora, voluptas cupiditate praesentium illo iure. Cupiditate, necessitatibus natus id eius nulla ab suscipit tempora nisi itaque omnis quas, voluptates accusantium cum labore nam. Laboriosam alias doloremque quos adipisci pariatur ipsum doloribus et cupiditate omnis cum, ducimus deleniti, sequi optio harum! Iste quas in, qui nobis voluptatibus quibusdam doloremque culpa, numquam officia incidunt, quidem! Asperiores omnis amet incidunt eveniet.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium animi sint officiis, voluptate nam vitae inventore minus aliquid temporibus soluta natus, qui repellendus ducimus eum veritatis neque impedit odio quibusdam.
  </p>
  <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur natus, facere nulla similique doloremque! Ullam voluptatem debitis esse. Deleniti quas, vel ad consectetur facilis ab consequatur voluptate aut optio odit nisi reprehenderit sint, ipsa incidunt itaque id voluptatum repudiandae alias esse velit quo voluptatibus recusandae earum eligendi! Est, quae, aliquam?
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, earum ullam hic id! Corporis cupiditate, voluptatibus eligendi suscipit ratione eos, sequi aperiam voluptatem laboriosam! Debitis consectetur eum aperiam similique ullam dolore, labore porro, sequi fuga atque, tempora, est delectus veniam! Ad tempora, voluptas cupiditate praesentium illo iure. Cupiditate, necessitatibus natus id eius nulla ab suscipit tempora nisi itaque omnis quas, voluptates accusantium cum labore nam. Laboriosam alias doloremque quos adipisci pariatur ipsum doloribus et cupiditate omnis cum, ducimus deleniti, sequi optio harum! Iste quas in, qui nobis voluptatibus quibusdam doloremque culpa, numquam officia incidunt, quidem! Asperiores omnis amet incidunt eveniet.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium animi sint officiis, voluptate nam vitae inventore minus aliquid temporibus soluta natus, qui repellendus ducimus eum veritatis neque impedit odio quibusdam.
    </p>
</main>
```

I have a page with smooth scroll & [element (leaft) with parallax effect](https://github.com/dixonandmoe/rellax).

For a smooth scrolling, I'm trying to use a mousewheel or here's a working version with tweenMax (I can't choose which option is better yet).

During the parallax of leaflets, the necessary transform is dynamically generated: `translate3d (...)`.

I would like to, when the scrolling stops, the rotation of the leaf starts somehow it is stopped to scroll the wheel (at this moment the page time will scroll itself by animation).

Example [brontidebg.com](https://www.brontidebg.com/), all the same I would like, but much easier with jquery.

**Question:**

How to start leaf animation (`rotateX(...)` right after the end of the scroll with the mousewheel, i.e., so that the rotation of the figure coincides with the animation of end? **Event a second before `onComplete`.**

Comment: Couldn't exactly understand your problem. Do you basically want to start the second animation just before the first one is about to end?